# Inhering only part of a function in Python

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes that inherit from the same parent class. Both have a function that is common only in part. For example both print `Hello` three times, but `Daughter1` will print `World` each time, and `Daughter2` will print the counter each time. This is how I am doing it now.

```
class Mother():
    def foo(self):
        for self.i in range(3):
            print('Hello')
            self.bar()
    def bar(self):
        print('This is just a dummy method')

class Daughter1(Mother):
    def bar(self):
        print('World')

class Daughter2(Mother):
    def bar(self):
        print(self.i)

d1 = Daughter1()
d1.foo()

d2 = Daughter2()
d2.foo()
```

It works, but I find it confusing and error prone. Is there a better way to do this?

Another alternative would be to implement the loop in the method of the daughters.

```
class Mother():
    def foo(self):
        print('Hello')

class Daughter1(Mother):
    def bar(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.foo()
            print('World')

class Daughter2(Mother):
    def bar(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.foo()
            print(i)

d1 = Daughter1()
d1.bar()
```

The problem here is that real loop is pretty complex, so I'd rather only code it once.

EDIT: I'll try to provide more context. I will add the code later because right now it's not working.
I am trying to write a code to create randomized exams. The code will
- Take a list of contacts
- Take a template of the exam
- Create a version of the exam with random numbers
- Create a PDF exam (using latex)
- Calculate and store the answers for each student
- Send an email to each student

I would like to use this for different subjects and different topics. Therefore, I decided to create a parent class `Exam`, and the create a new class for each exam that inherits from it (e.g. StatisticsExam`).`Exam`takes care of:
 - Looping through the list of contacts
 - Calling a function`create_exam()` that will be different for each of the daughters.
 - Creating the PDF
 - Cleaning up all the byproducts of latex.
 - Send an email to each student

In a very simplified way, it will work like this

```
import os.path as path
import pandas as pd

class Exam():
    def all_exams(self):
        contacts = pd.read_csv(path.join('contacts',self.grade + 'contacts.txt'))

        for _, person in contacts.iterrows(): 
            self.lastName = person['last name'] # Will be used in the daughter class
            self.firstName = person['first name']  # Will be used in the daughter class

            self.create_exam()

            self.create_pdf()

            self.email()

    def create_exam(self):
        exam = self.exam_headig()
        exam = exam + 'This is a dummy exam\n'
        exam = exam + self.exam_end()

        self.exam = exam



class StatisticsExam(Exam):
    def create_exam(self):
        self.exam_heading()
        self.statistics_exercise1()
        self.exam_end()


exam = StatisticsExam('statistics','9A')
exam.all_exams()
```

Maybe this is the wrong approach from the start...

Comment: This simplified version smells a bit - we probably need to see the full code to know what you're trying to achieve/how it differs.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you could provide more context this would definitely help.

Comment: Your first version is an example of the [template design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: I edited the original post to try add some more context. Sorry if it's messy, but I have no formal training in OOP

Comment: @match, I edited the question to provide more context, as you requested. Is that enough or should I add more?

Comment: @a_guest  I edited the question to provide more context, as you requested. Is that enough or should I add more?

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is the good one.

Now, alternatively and depending of what you are trying to achieve you could do something like:

```
class Mother():

    bar = ''

    def foo(self):
        for self.i in range(3):
            print('Hello {}'.format(self.bar))


class Daughter1(Mother):
    bar = 'world'

class Daughter2(Mother):

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self.i


d1 = Daughter1()
d1.foo()

d2 = Daughter2()
d2.foo()
```

For a simple `print` function it makes a bit more sens.
As you can see it uses [@property](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#property) decorator to output `self.i`.

Answer (score 1):

You;re right that your first implementation is confusing/error prone - if nothing else it is never safe to call `bar` in `Daughter2` unless something else has already set `self.i`. This will make it tricky to test, debug and document.

It is probably clearer to make `bar` a method that prints a value defined in the class, OR the value passed in to the method. This means that the child classes are much simpler to implement. For example:

```
class Mother():
    def foo(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print('Hello')
            self.bar(i)
    def bar(self, val):
        if hasattr(self, 'print_val'):
            val = self.print_val
        print(val)

class Daughter1(Mother):
    def __init__(self):
        self.print_val = 'World'

class Daughter2(Mother):
    pass

d1 = Daughter1()
d1.foo()

d2 = Daughter2()
d2.foo()
```